# How to access the "Fetch as Google" tool?

Tags: google-search-console, fetch-as-google, url-inspection-tool

In [Hacked Sites Troubleshooter - Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/troubleshooter/6155978#ts=6155992%2C6157704), there is a tutorial to find hacked content:

> Use the [Fetch as Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch?utm_source=HackedTS&utm_medium=HelpCenter&utm_campaign=HackedTS) tool in Webmaster Tools to check suspicious pages for hacked content.
>
> Hackers often try to hide hacked content on your site to prevent it from being easily removed. Even if a page appears normal or even removed to you, it's possible there is still hacked content on it. When you use the Fetch as Google tool, you see the page as Google would see it. That way you can see if there is any live spammy content on your page.
>
> [image]

However, when I click on the [Fetch as Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch?utm_source=HackedTS&utm_medium=HelpCenter&utm_campaign=HackedTS) link, it just redirects me to the main page of Google Search Console: https://search.google.com/search-console. I don't know how to use the fetch tool.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google retired the "Fetch as Google" tool and replaced it with the [URL inspection tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en).  Specifically you want to use the "Test Live URL" option and then "View Tested Page."

[image]

You can also get into the URL inspection tool by clicking the magnifying glass next to URLs in the Google Search Console coverage report.

[image]

Comment: is there a way to request indexing many pages without using sitemap? I have many pages that are excluded and want to be indexed again

Comment: Creating and submitting a temporary sitemap of changed URLs and submitting that sitemap MAY get Googlebot to come crawl them and reconsider them.     I've seen Google's John Mueller recommend that, but I've also seen that it sometimes doesn't trigger any crawling or indexing.   Inspect URL is more reliable, but it is a one URL at a time option.